# Scroll View only works on TextView and not entire Layout

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I want to make my page scroll down in my app so i can see the rest of my TextView (txtDescricaoLocal), but the scroll only works within the TextView and not the whole page.
I can´t seem to find any error on the scroll view and the relative layout.
How can i make the scroll work on the entire layout instead of only in txtDescricaoLocal ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descricao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtDescricaoLocal"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtHorariosLocal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-31dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/descriçaoLocal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescricaoLocal"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/localNav"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/viewPagerLocal"

            android:layout_alignStart="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_width="344dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.308" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/estrelaIndicaFavorito"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:tint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/localNav"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SliderDots"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,NotSibling,VectorDrawableCompat" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textContactos"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:text="@string/Contactos"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtContactosLocal"
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textContactos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHorarios"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtContactosLocal"
            android:text="@string/horarios"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHorariosLocal"
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_below="@id/textHorarios" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/localNav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDescricaoLocal"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_local_items"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:layout_width="361dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewPagerLocal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtDescricaoLocal"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```